# How to get the Unicode character from a code point variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, hebrew

I have a variable which stores the string `"u05e2"` (The value is constantly changing because I set it within a loop). I want to print the Hebrew letter with that Unicode value. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
>>> a = 'u05e2'
>>> print(u'\{}'.format(a))
```

I got `\u05e2` instead of `ע`(In this case).

I also tried to do:

```
>>> a = 'u05e2'
>>> b = '\\' + a
>>> print(u'{}'.format(b))
```

Neither one worked. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution suggested there worked for me.Thanks!

Comment: That SO answer points to a solution for Python 2.7 where explicit unicode conversion was required. In Python 3, this is built into str() and should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a `\` before `u05e2`. To print a Unicode character, you must provide a unicode format string.

```
a = '\u05e2'
print(u'{}'.format(a))

#Output
ע
```

When you try the other approach by printing the `\` within the `print()` function, Python first escapes the `\` and does not show the desired result.

```
a = 'u05e2'
print(u'\{}'.format(a))

#Output
\u05e2
```

A way to verify the validity of Unicode format strings is using the `ord()` built-in function in the Python standard library. This returns the Unicode code point(an integer) of the character passed to it. This function only expects either a Unicode character or a string representing a Unicode character.

```
a = '\u05e2'
print(ord(a)) #1506, the Unicode code point for the Unicode string stored in a
```

To print the Unicode character for the above Unicode code value(1506), use the character type formatting with `c`. This is explained in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

```
print('{0:c}'.format(1506))

#Output
ע
```

If we pass a normal string literal to `ord()`, we get an error. This is because this string does not represent a Unicode character.

```
a = 'u05e2'
print(ord(a))

#Error
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 5 found
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  If you want the Unicode character for a code point, use an integer variable and the function `chr` (or `unichr` on Python 2) instead of trying to format an escape code:

```
>>> for a in range(0x5e0,0x5eb):
...  print(hex(a),chr(a))
...
0x5e0 נ
0x5e1 ס
0x5e2 ע
0x5e3 ף
0x5e4 פ
0x5e5 ץ
0x5e6 צ
0x5e7 ק
0x5e8 ר
0x5e9 ש
0x5ea ת
```

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because you have to add the suffix `u` outside of the string.

```
a = u'\u05e2'
print(a)
ע
```

Hope this helps you.